# Validation Erroron the heading

Tags: javascript, html, validation, dom

When I try to validate this code on W3c Validator it is giving me an error of

Line 55, Column 38: Bad value for attribute action on element form: Must be non-empty.

Syntax of IRI reference:
Any URL. For example: /hello, #canvas, or http://example.org/. Characters should be represented in NFC and spaces should be escaped as %20.

I have tried looking over it and trying to fix other things, but I can't find anything wrong with it. Here is all my code for it. If you see anything wrong, please let me know to fix this error! Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>JackHammer</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    /* <![CDATA[ */
    /* ]]> */

    var jackhammers = new Array(11);
    var curJackhammer = 0;
    var direction;
    var begin;
    jackhammers[0] = "jackhammer0.gif";
    jackhammers[1] = "jackhammer1.gif";
    jackhammers[2] = "jackhammer2.gif";
    jackhammers[3] = "jackhammer3.gif";
    jackhammers[4] = "jackhammer4.gif";
    jackhammers[5] = "jackhammer5.gif";
    jackhammers[6] = "jackhammer6.gif";
    jackhammers[7] = "jackhammer7.gif";
    jackhammers[8] = "jackhammer8.gif";
    jackhammers[9] = "jackhammer9.gif";
    jackhammers[10] = "jackhammer10.gif";

    function bounce() {
        if (curJackhammer == 10)
            curJackhammer = 0;
        else
            ++curJackhammer;
        document.getElemensByTagName(
            "img")[0].src
            = jackhammers[curJacHammer].src;
        if (curJackhammer == 0)
            direction = "up";
        else if (curJackhammer ==1-)
            direction = "down";
        document.getElemensByTagName(
            "img")[0].src
            = jackhammers[curJacHammer];
    }
    function startBouncing() {
        if (begin)
            clearIntercal(begin);
        begin = setIntercal("bounce()",90);
    }

    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Jackhammer Man</h1>
    <p><img src="jachammer1.gif" height="113" width="100"
    alt="Image of a man with a jackhammer." /></p>
    <form action="" enctype="text/plain"><p>
    <input type="button"
    value="Start Bouncing"
    onclick="startbouncing();" />
    <input type="button" value="Stop Bouncing"
    onclick="clearInterval(begin);" /></p>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you have empty action parameter here:

```
<form action="" enctype="text/plain"><p>
```

As simple as this...

Put there path to a file to which form should be sent or at least `#`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `form` markup entirely. You do not need it, because you are not submitting form data to server or otherwise using anything related to a `form` element. Your buttons work just fine without any `form` element (when client-side scripting is enabled, and when it is not, they won’t work anyway).

HTML5 drafts (which is what you are validating against) for some reason disallow an empty value for `action`. They do allow the omission of an `action` attribute, defaulting to the address of the document itself, so you could just delete the attribute. But it is better to get rid of the `form` markup entirely.